# Regex por posição PHP

Tags: php, regex

Tenho a seguinte string:

```
'QD 10 LT 20 PA 30'
```

Usando o `preg_replace()` no PHP consigo manipular apenas os números.

Por exemplo, pegar o primeiro grupo de números:

```
$string = 'QD 10 LT 20 PA 30'
preg_replace('/\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)/', '$1', $string)
//return 10
```

Há alguma forma de fazer o padrão ser recursivo?

Por exemplo o regex `/\D+(\d+)/` separar todos números em grupos de acordo com a quantidade de grupos de números. Ou seja, caso minha string fosse maior (`'QD 10 LT 20 PA 30 SC 40'`), eu não precisaria aumentar o meu regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Na pergunta é mencionado que você quer pegar apenas o primeiro número, mas depois diz que também quer pegar todos. Então deixei uma solução para cada caso.*</sup>

---

### Pegar apenas o primeiro número

Se você só quer extrair um trecho da string que corresponde à regex, pode usar [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), passando a sua string e uma variável que conterá os *matches*:

```
$string = 'QD 10 LT 20 PA 30';
preg_match('/^\D+(\d+)\D+/', $string, $matches);
echo($matches[1]);
```

No caso, usei o [marcador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^`, que indica o início da string. Em seguida, eu verifico até o primeiro grupo de dígitos (`(\d+)`). Como você só quer saber do primeiro grupo, não precisa verificar o restante da string.

A variável `$matches` conterá os trechos que a regex capturar. E como `\d+` está dentro de parênteses, será formado um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). E como é o primeiro par de parênteses, ele estará disponível em `$matches[1]`. Por isso esse código imprime `10`.

---

Há um detalhe na regex. Logo depois do `^` há o `\D+` (um ou mais caracteres que não sejam números). Isso quer dizer que a string não pode começar com números. Ou seja, este código não imprime nada, pois como a string começa com números, o `preg_match` retorna `false`:

```
$string = '11 QD 10 LT 20 PA 30'; // começa com números (não entra no if)
if (preg_match('/^\D+(\d+)\D+/', $string, $matches)) {
    echo ($matches[1]);
}
```

Sendo assim, uma alternativa é trocar o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` (uma ou mais ocorrências) por `*` (zero ou mais ocorrências):

```
$string = '11 QD 10 LT 20 PA 30'; // começa com números
if (preg_match('/^\D*(\d+)\D+/', $string, $matches)) { // troquei o primeiro \D+ por \D*
    echo ($matches[1]); // agora entra no if
}
```

---

Mas há outro porém. Pelo que entendi, você também quer validar se a string está no formato "duas letras, dois números, duas letras, dois números, etc".

Vamos assumir que o formato é exatamente esse (sempre duas letras e dois números, separados por espaço, e este padrão pode se repetir várias vezes). Neste caso, podemos trocar o `+` por `{2}`, que significa ["exatamente duas ocorrências"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit):

```
$string = 'QD 10 LT 20 PA 30 SC 40';
if (preg_match('/^[A-Z]{2} (\d{2})( [A-Z]{2} \d{2})*$/', $string, $matches)) {
    echo ($matches[1]); // 10
}
```

Primeiro temos o início da string (`^`), e em seguida `[A-Z]{2} (\d{2})`:

- `[A-Z]{2}` significa "2 letras de `A` a `Z`" (somente maiúsculas). Se quiser somente letras minúsculas, troque por `[a-z]{2}`, e se tanto faz maiúsculas quanto minúsculas, use `[A-Za-z]{2}`
- depois temos um espaço em branco (já que os campos são separados por um espaço)
- depois temos `(\d{2})`: dois dígitos dentro de um grupo de captura (para que esteja em `$matches[1]`)

Depois temos `( [A-Z]{2} \d{2})*`. Dentro dos parênteses temos um espaço (repare no espaço logo depois do `(`), seguido de duas letras, outro espaço e dois dígitos. Fora dos parênteses temos `*`, o que significa que toda essa sequência (espaço, 2 letras, espaço, 2 dígitos) pode se repetir zero ou mais vezes. Isso garante que a sua string pode ser tanto `QD 10 LT 20 PA 30 SC 40` quanto `QD 10`.

Por fim, temos `$`, que significa "final da string". Com isso eu garanto que a string toda possui o formato que preciso, e ainda pego o primeiro grupo de dígitos em `$matches[1]`.

Se a quantidade de letras e dígitos pode variar, basta mudar o quantificador. Exemplos:

- `\d{1,5}` - entre 1 e 5 dígitos
- `\d{2,}` - 2 ou mais dígitos (sem limite máximo)

Ajuste para os valores que você precisar.

---

### Pegar todos os números

Neste caso, use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
$string = 'QD 10 LT 20 PA 30 SC 40';

if (preg_match_all('/\b(\d{2})\b/', $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    foreach ($matches as $m) {
        echo $m[1] . "\n";
    }
}
```

Neste caso, estou usando `\b` como delimitador, pois ele representa uma ["fronteira de palavras"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), que na prática verifica se há algum caractere não alfa-numérico antes e depois do `(\d{2})`. A diferença é que agora `$matches` conterá um array com todas as ocorrências de 2 dígitos da string. A saída é:

> 10
>   20
>   30
>   40

A diferença é que o `preg_match_all` só está pegando os dígitos, mas não valida de fato o formato da string. Ou seja, se a string for `abcdef 10, xyz!20`, ainda sim ela pegará os números.

Mas você pode usar a regex anterior somente para validar o formato, e em seguida usar `preg_match_all` para extrair os números:

```
$string = 'QD 10 LT 20 PA 30 SC 40';
// verifica o formato da string
if (preg_match('/^[A-Z]{2} (\d{2})( [A-Z]{2} \d{2})*$/', $string)) {
    // só extraio os números se o formato estiver OK
    if (preg_match_all('/\b(\d{2})\b/', $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
        foreach ($matches as $m) {
            echo $m[1] . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isso já me ajuda muito. 
Eu queria fazer com o replace pois a posição e o regex é o cliente que define. Então em vez de usar o match_all e digitar as posições de cada número de 0 à 2 , por exemplo, ele digitaria de 1 à 3 apenas à fim de ser visualmente mais claro.
Eu cheguei a ver alguns comandos de recursividade no regex mas não consegui chegar no que eu queria.